# Find a matrix $A$ with no zero entries such that $A^3=A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I took a standard $2 × 2$ matrix with entries $a, b, c, d$ and multiplied it out three times and tried to algebraically make it work, but that quickly turned into a algebraic mess. Is there an easier method to solve this?

Comment: Hint: $A$ will satisfy the polynomial $x^3 = x$. This will be the characteristic equation.

Comment: I have never tried this before , but how do we turn x(x-1)(x+1)=0 into a matrix? I assume 1 is the identity matrix right?

Comment: Do you know about the characteristic equation and eigenvalue?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why no one has yet posted

$$(1)^3=(1)$$

Comment: This is clever, but I am sure the OP wanted $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Possibly, but wasn't stated in the actual question. Just what they tried.

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach is noticing that if $A^3 = A$, then $A^2 = I$, which should be much more tractable.  This also means that $A = A^{-1}$ and you can equate the generic abcd with its inverse.  Further, the determinant of A must be 1 or -1, since it squares to 1.  So that simplifies the inverse formula too.

Addendum: if $A^3 = A$, then $det(A)^3 = det(A)$ so $det(A)$ satisfies $x^3 = x$, which has solutions x = 1, 0, and -1. If x = 1 or -1, $A$ is invertible and the above description works.  If $A$ is not invertible, then it must have two rows or columns that are proportional, which is a further simplification for the search.

Comment: Caveat: what you say is true if $A$ is invertible, but of course is false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to notice that if $A^2 = A$, then $A^3 = A  A^2 = A^2 = A$. So it suffices to find a matrix with $A^2 = A$. Since $A$ is square these are matrices associated to [projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)) (not neccesarily orthogonal projections). It's much easier to algebraicly solve $A^2 = A$ for the entires. As an example,

$$A = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

will do what you want.

Comment: Where did the A^2=A come from? Is that just as assumption to simplify the problem? Oh I think that was a typo right?

Comment: A^2 does not equal A here though, we are off by a scalar. The matrix is correct though

Comment: @William the $A^2=A$ came from intuition and recognizing that given an example where it *were* true it would trivially lead to an example that you were looking for.  "*We are off by a scalar*" Yes, it looks like Zorngo was accidentally solving for the scalar which makes $A^2$ equal to the matrix with all ones.  The scalar should have been $\dfrac{1}{2}$, not $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ (*found by solving $2x^2=x$*)

Comment: @William The $A^2 = A$ came precicely from where JMoravitz said, realising that IF $A^2 = A$ it would solve the problem. Of course this does not find all matrices such that $A^3 = A$, just a particular sub-family. I also fixed the typo with the scalar.

Answer (score 1):

If $ad-bc=1,$ with $a,b,c,d$ non-zero, you can use:

$$\begin{pmatrix}-bc&-bd\\ac&ad\end{pmatrix}$$

For example, $a=2,b=1,c=1,d=1$ gives:

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\2&2\end{pmatrix}$$

I got this by taking:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

Where $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ satisfies $B^2=B$ and hence $B^3=B.$

You can also choose $B=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ or $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$

Answer (score 1):

One way to simplify the problem is to impose some further assumptions on $A$. For example, suppose we further assume that $A$ is singular. Then $A=uv^T$ for some entrywise vectors $u$ and $v$. The requirements that $A^3=A$ and $A\ne0$ entrywise are now equivalent to $(v^Tu)^2=1$ and $u,v\ne0$ entrywise, which are utterly easy to fulfil (when the characteristic of the underlying field is not $2$).

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{pmatrix}7&-6\\8&-7\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How does it not answer the question?  It seems to be correct.

Comment: I think you ought to improve this post by explaining how you got this matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It is useful to think about a problem like that in geometric terms.

We want to have $ A^3=A $ which could be thought as some kind of rotation of the plane.

Along these lines what we want is if we rotate a vector by $\theta $ under $A$ to be equal to a rotation by $3 \theta$ corresponding to $A^3$.

A rotation by $\theta$ is given by $A_\theta= 
\left (\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta  &  \cos \theta
\end{array} \right )$.

So if we choose $\theta = \pi = 3\theta  ~\text{mod} 2 \pi $

We get
$$A_{\pi/2}= 
\left (\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0\\
0  &  1
\end{array} \right ).$$

Which should satisfy $$ A_{\pi}^3 = A_{\pi} $$

We can also change the coordinates by $\pi/3$ so to eliminate the zeros.
So we define
\begin{align*}
A &= A_{\pi/3}  A_{\pi} A_{-\pi/3} \\
&=  \left (\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}\\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}} &  \frac{1}{2}
\end{array} \right ) \cdot  \left (\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0\\
0  &  1
\end{array} \right ) \cdot \left (\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}\\
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}} &  \frac{1}{2}
\end{array} \right ) 
\end{align*}

Comment: "*with no zero entries*"

Comment: All the entries needs to be nonzero. I thought about rotation at first, but I can't find a way to get rid of the nonzero entries

Comment: @JMoravitz good catch!

Comment: @William changing the coordinates afterwards fixes it. Although it is not as immediate as before

Comment: Note that $\det(A) = -1$, so $A$ isn't a rotation; it's a reflection.

Answer (score 0):

$A^3=A$ can be written as $A(A-I)(A+I)=0$, which is satisfied by any matrix that is similar to a $2x2$ diagonal matrix with diagonals in the set $\{0,1,-1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos t & \sin t \\
\sin t & - \cos t
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

with eigenvectors as columns of

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \frac{t}{2} & -\sin  \frac{t}{2} \\
\sin  \frac{t}{2} &  \cos \frac{t}{2}
\end{array}
\right) \; \; , \; \;
$$

this confirmed by the identity

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos t & \sin t \\
\sin t & - \cos t
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \frac{t}{2} & -\sin  \frac{t}{2} \\
\sin  \frac{t}{2} &  \cos \frac{t}{2}
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \frac{t}{2} & \sin  \frac{t}{2} \\
\sin  \frac{t}{2} & - \cos \frac{t}{2}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

It does not need to be symmetric, although the reflection is what first came to mind for $M^2 = I,$  which happens when $M^3 = M$ and $M$ is nonsingular. For real matrices, we need just trace zero and determinant $-1$

As  long as $$ a^2 + bc = 1 $$  we can use
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & - a
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

for example

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
7 & 8 \\
-6 & - 7
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

We see the eigenvectors as columns

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & - a
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1+a & -b \\
c & 1+ a
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1+a & -b \\
c & -1- a
\end{array}
\right) 
$$